# I think I have problem with basics about FME and Python

Tags: python, fme-form

I try to learn from Oliver's corner instruction ftp://ftp.safe.com/fme/pyfme/OliversCorner.zip) . So for example I overwrite his #script 4 to StartupPython Script some below and set input data in workflow with name "Fruits":

```
class MyPythonFactory(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.count_features = 0
         self.logger = pyfme.FMELogfile()

     def input(self,feature):
         self.count_features += 1

         # Accessing all attributes of a feature
         self.all_attributes = 'Tile'.getAllAttributeNames() # return a list with all attribute names as result
         self.all_attributes_count = len(self.all_attributes) # count attributes

         self.logger.log('Feature: '+ str(self.count_features),1)

         for i in range(self.all_attributes_count):
             self.attribute_name  = self.all_attributes[i]                     # get attribute name
             self.attribute_value = 'Tile'.getAttribute(self.attribute_name)  # get attribute value
             self.logger.log('Attribute: ' + str(self.attribute_name) + '\tValue: ' + str(self.attribute_value), 1)

         self.logger.log('\n',1)
         self.pyoutput('Tile')

     def close(self):
         self.logger.log('Total number of features: ' + str(self.count_features),1)
```

And according to this I should get following results in log file:

```
 Feature: 1
 Attribute: X_INT   Value: 3333317
 Attribute: ID  Value: 1
 Attribute: fme_type    Value: fme_point
 Attribute: LASTNAME    Value: von Goethe
 Attribute: Y_INT   Value: 5684892
 Attribute: fme_feature_type    Value: points
 Attribute: fme_geometry    Value: fme_point
 Attribute: SHAPE_GEOMETRY  Value: shape_point
 Attribute: X_FLOAT Value: 3333317
 Attribute: SURNAME Value: Johann Wolfgang
 Attribute: Y_FLOAT Value: 5684892
```

But I do not get any results of this script in logfile!

So my questions are:

1. How script recognize which feature I will use If there are more? Is feature name actually name of input data for example, so I should use 'Fruits'?
2. Do I have to replace word 'feature' in code with corresponding feature name in workbench?

Comment: Please provide a link to the original code that you are modifying.

Comment: link is above. Thank you very much for suggestioN!

Comment: Personally I have not been able to get a grasp of Python in FME either, except for scripted parameters. Thankfully they are rewriting the Python FME API (and actually documenting it this time) for FME 2012: http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/FAQ/What-Happened-to-Oliver-s-Python-Corner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Python snippet is not appropriate for a Startup Python Script.  It's purpose is to process features, so you need to place it in a PythonCaller transformer.

http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/content/transformers/pythoncaller.htm

Startup Python Scripts would not typically operate on features, but could be used to do more generic preparation before the workspace is run.